# "Efficient version" of Cayley's Theorem in Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm considering finite groups only.
Cayley's theorem says the a group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{|G|}$.
I think it's interesting to ask for smaller values of $n$ for which $G$ is a subgroup of $S_n$. Obviously, it's not always possible to do better than Cayley's theorem. But sometimes it is possible (for example, $\mathbb{Z}_6$ as a subgroup of $S_5$).

So I'm asking:

> 1. Given a finite group $G$, is there an algorithmic way to find or approximate the minimal $n$ for which $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$?
> 2. If the answer to $(1)$ is not known, is it known for specific classes of groups?
> 3. In particular, for finite abelian groups, is it true that for a prime $p$, the minimal $n$ for $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{t_1}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^{t_2}}$ is $p^{t_1}+p^{t_2}$ (I can prove that is is true for different primes $p_1$ and $p_2$, but have problems when it's the same prime in both factors).

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a relevant question from MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16858/smallest-permutation-representation-of-a-finite-group

Comment: The answer to 1 is obviously yes - you are presumably looking for an efficient algorithm. The answer to 3 is also yes. You should follow Rose's advice and look at the discussion on MO.

Comment: A simple (no pun intended) special case: If $G$ is simple then the smallest $n$ for which we have an injective homomorphism into $S_n$ is the smallest index of a proper subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen, why don't you make your comment an answer? The answer you link to on mathoverflow answers this question quite well.

Comment: @JamesMitchell: Done.

Comment: Related: [Finding the smallest set on which a group acts faithfully](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522901/finding-the-smallest-set-on-which-a-group-acts-faithfully)

Answer (score 11):

The following question from MathOverflow should answer your questions and more: [Smallest permutation representation of a finite group?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16858/smallest-permutation-representation-of-a-finite-group)

The answer to 3) is yes, and more generally if $G$ is a finite abelian group such that

$$G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{a_1}} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{p_t^{a_t}}$$

where $p_i$ are prime and $a_i \geq 1$, then the minimal $n$ is $p_1^{a_1} + \cdots + p_t^{a_t}$. A proof can be found in the following paper that Jack Schmidt mentions in his MO answer.

> Johnson, D. L. "Minimal permutation representations of finite groups." Amer. J. Math. 93 (1971), 857-866. [MR 316540](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=316540) [DOI: 10.2307/2373739](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2373739).