# Finding the minimal $n$ so $A_n$ has an element of order $x$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Consider the Alternating group ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group)): $A_n=\{\sigma\in S_{n}\,:\,sign(\sigma)=1\}$.

I would like to find the minimal $n$ so $A_n$ has an element of order $x$.

For example, how can I find the minimal $n$ so $A_n$ has an element of order $4$.

Where should I start? How should I build $\sigma$?

Comment: It would improve your Question to add some context to the problem statement.  Why is the problem interesting to you?  If you've tried to solve it, what difficulty or partial success resulted?  In general it helps Readers to know that you've digested the problem statement at least enough to recognize a valid or useful Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x$ factorises and has $p^r$ as the highest power of the prime $p$. The cycle decomposition of the element $e$ needs to have a component of length $p^r$. If $p$ is $2$ you need to add a transposition to make the element even rather than odd.

This works because $(a-1)(b-1)\gt 0 \implies ab\ge a+b$ with $ab\gt a+b$ in the cases of interest - where $a$ and $b$ are powers of different primes.

So for $18$ you would need a nine-cycle and two transpositions to give $n=13$. For $15$ you could do a three cycle and a five cycle with $n=8$.

For $4$ the answer is $6$ with a four-cycle and a transposition.

---

So the way this works is this. An element $e$ of a symmetric or alternating group has a decomposition into disjoint cycles. The order of the element is the least common multiple of the orders of the cycles.

Here note that the cycles permute different elements of the underlying set, so they commute. Suppose the cycles are $a, b, c$ for example, with orders $d, e, f$ whose least common multiple is $m$. We have $(abc)^m=a^mb^mc^m=1$. And suppose there is some $k$ with $k\lt m$ and $(abc)^k=1$, then at least one of $d,e,f$ is not a factor of $k$, say $d$. Then $a^k=b^{m-k}c^{m-k}\neq 1$ expresses $a^k$ as a product of powers of $b$ and $c$, but this is absurd because they move disjoint subsets of the underlying set and can't be equal.

To minimise the total length of the cycles for an element of order $x$ we make them pairwise coprime.

Reason [amended in edit] - if we have cycles of length $ab$ and $ac$, where $b$ and $c$ are coprime and $a\gt 1$, let $d$ be the highest common factor of $a$ and $b$ and $a=de$. We then have that $d$ and $c$ are coprime, and also that $b$ and $e$ are coprime so that $bd$ and $ce$ are coprime. If we now use cycles of length $bd$ and $ce$ we have that $bd+ce\lt ab+ac$ and $bcde=abc$.

For order $p^r$ with $p$ a prime we can't do better than a cycle of length $p^r$ permuting $p^r$ elements.

This means that if we have a target order $$x=\prod p_i^{r_i} $$ where the primes $p_i$ are the distinct primes which divide $x$, we can split into disjoint cycles of coprime length $p_i^{r_i}$ which permute at least $$\sum p_i^{r_i}$$elements, where the sum is over the distinct primes dividing $x$ with their respective exponents. In the symmetric group, this is sufficient. If one of the $p_i=2$, there will be one cycle of even length, which is therefore an odd permutation. If we want to be in the alternating group we have to multiply by a further transposition in this case, and add $2$ to the sum. We can do this, if we want to as $$n=\sum \left(p_i^{r_i}+(-1)^{p_i}+1\right)$$ .

Comment: Interestingly, the resulting sequence $(1,4,3,6,5,5,7,10,9,...)$ is not on the OEIS.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you for the answer. I don't really understand the intuition. What are $x$ and $r$?

Comment: $x$ is the order of the element you construct. $r$ is the exponent of the prime $p$ in $n$. Find the cycle composition of element $e$ - its order is the least common multiple of the cycle lengths.

Comment: @MarkBennet good answer. Where can I find a proper proof of this statement?

Comment: What do you mean by factorises ?

Comment: @TTaJTa4:  At a glance I do not find a complete proof of the order of a permutation being the least common denominator of disjoint cycle lengths in any such representation, although the topic has come up a number of times from the earliest days of Math.SE.  Certainly it would be good for Math.SE to have a sound treatment of the proof.

Comment: What can we say about order $3$?

Comment: @hardmath I have filled out an answer in case that helps. Feel free to comment on how it could be improved.

Comment: @vesii For an element of order $3$ you need a three cycle and $S_3$ will do.

Comment: @Mark: There's a slight slip in your first comment, where $r$ is the power of $p$ in a factorization of $x$, not $n$.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon That is a surprise (OEIS).

Comment: @TTaJTa4: The order of a (finite) permutation being the LCM of the lengths of cycles in its disjoint cycle representation follows from the more abstract result about commuting products of group elements with coprime orders.  A short but satisfactory proof is given here, [Order of the product of two commuting elements with coprime orders in a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526409/order-of-the-product-of-two-commuting-elements-with-coprime-orders-in-a-group).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for the link. I've added further details here and given a proof which exploits the fact that we are in a permutation group and the cycles are disjoint.

Comment: While @Pierre-GuyPlamondon observed that the sequence here is not found in OEIS, the corresponding sequence for the symmetric group $S_n$ differs only in a simple even-odd cadence.  [OEIS A222416](https://oeis.org/A222416) gives the latter, i.e. the sum of the prime power factors of $x$.

Comment: I would simplify the final expression for $n$ to $1 + (-1)^x + \sum p_i^{r_i}$.  It makes it more apparent that the extra summand $2$ depends only on whether $x$ is even or odd.

Comment: See also [OEIS A008475](http://oeis.org/A008475) which differs from the above sequence A222416 only in the value "by convention" for $x=1$.  That older OEIS sequence was pointed out in answer to the closely related Question, [What is the smallest degree symmetric group with an element of order 50?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692788/what-is-the-smallest-degree-symmetric-group-with-an-element-of-order-50)