# Is Cayley's theorem tight in a sense?

Tags: group-theory

For any $n$, does there exist a group $G$ of order $n$ so that $G$ is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $S_j$ for $j<n$?

Comment: Cayley's theorem is for "*every group*".

Comment: Whenever $n$ is a prime number the (up to isomorphism) only group of order $n$ has this property. But what exactly is the question? For which $n$ does there exist such a group, or? AFAICT $n=4$ also works.

Comment: @lhf that is the title and also the description. What is unclear?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That is exactly the question.

Comment: For *any*  (= *some*) or for *every* $n$?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191446/efficient-version-of-cayleys-theorem-in-group-theory.

Comment: @lhf Thanks! The link answer my question, should this be marked as duplicate or....?

Comment: @user336-iactuallychosethis: Yes, we appreciate when the OP himself closes his question as a duplicate (it is faster, too, because no extra votes are required then).