# Cayley's theorem: Is $C_5$ isomorphic to $ \langle (1 2 3 4 5) \rangle \leq S_{5}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

I want to use Cayley's theorem to determine a subgroup in $S_n$ ( for n as small as possible) which is isomorphic to $C_{5}$.

I believe this subgroup to be $ \langle (1 2 3 4 5)  \rangle $. Here is my reasoning:

$C_5 =  \{ e, g, g^2, g^3, g^4\}$ is generated and hence determined by $g$. The isomorphism $ \rho$ used in the proof of Cayley's theorem maps $g$ to $(1 2 3 4 5)$ in $S_5$. But since $ \rho $ is a homomorphism, $ \rho(C_5) =  \langle (1 2 3 4 5)  \rangle.$ Therefore, $C_5   \cong  \langle (1 2 3 4 5)  \rangle.$

Is this correct? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the "$n$ as small as possible" part see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191446/efficient-version-of-cayleys-theorem-in-group-theory

Comment: It's clear that $S_5$ is minimal for this.  If $n<5$ then $5\,\nmid \,n!$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see what Cayley's theorem has to do with anything; it gives you an embedding of your group into some symmetric group, but gives you no guarantees of that being the *smallest* symmetric group.

In stead, a quick check will show that $S_n$ has no elements of order $5$ for $n<5$. And you have found a subgroup of order $5$ in $S_5$, hence $n=5$ is the smallest $n$ for which such a subgroup exists. Done.

Comment: Thanks! I see how this quickly gives the least $n$. But, regardless, is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @wittbluenote Your reasoning shows that $S_5$ has such a subgroup. You have yet to show that $n$ is as small as possible.

Comment: I understand now, thank you!