# Does there exist some sort of classification of incompressible groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-actions

It is well known, that any finite group of order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$. Let’s call a finite group $G$ *incompressible* iff it is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $S_{|G|-1}$ . Does there exist some sort of classification of *incompressible* groups?

What I currently know:

> Any  non-trivial incompressible group has non-trivial center

If the center of a group $G$ is trivial, then it acts faithfully by conjugation on $G \setminus \{e\}$.

> If an incompressible group is non-trivially decomposed into a direct product of two its subgroups, it is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$

One can construct a faithful action of $H \times K$ on $H \cup K$. It is defined as $(h, k)h_0 \mapsto hh_0$ and $(h, k)h_0 \mapsto kk_0$ for $h, h_0 \in H$, $k, k_0 \in K$.

$|H| + |K| \geq |H||K|$ iff either one of the groups is trivial, or both of them are isomorphic to $C_2$.

$C_2 \times C_2$ is the only possible group and indeed is not contained in $S_3$.

I also conjecture, that «direct product» in this statement can be replaced with «semidirect product», but do not know how to prove that.

> All cyclic $p$-groups are incompressible

If $p$ is prime, then $S_{p^n - 1}$ does not have an element of order $p^n$

> $Q_8$ is incompressible

$S_7$ does not contain $Q_8$ as a subgroup

Comment: According to Jack Schmidt's answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16858/, the only examples are $C_2\times C_2$, cyclic groups of prime power order, and (generalized) quaternion groups. He gives a reference to a paper by D.L Johnson.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191446/efficient-version-of-cayleys-theorem-in-group-theory

Comment: You could have considered another word for the definition. 

Comment: Why "horny"?!?!

Comment: I agree, why not change it into _corny_

Comment: At the risk of being boring, I have seen such groups be called 'incompressible'

Comment: Well I dislike "horny" because I find it  distracting.

Comment: I'm not sure they deserve any name at all.

Comment: Maybe we should also include ***horny infinite groups.***  That is, an infinite group $G$ that cannot be embedded into $\text{Perm}(S)$ for any set $S$ such that $|S|<|G|$, where $\text{Perm}(S)$ is the group  of permutations on a set $S$.  From the link here, all countably infinite groups are horny: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398044.

Comment: I've changed the sexually connoted word "horny" into "incompressible", which was the only suggested choice so far in the comments.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These were fully classified by Johnson in the paper 'Minimal Permutation Representations of Finite Groups'.

A group is incompressible iff it is isomorphic to one of the following:

- Cyclic group of prime power order $C_{p^n}$
- Generalised quaternion $2$-group $\langle x,y|x^{2^n}=1,x^{2^{n-1}}=y^2,x^y=x^{-1}\rangle$
- the Klein four-group $C_2\times C_2$

The proof is reasonably short so well worth looking up!

Reference: Johnson, D. L. "Minimal permutation representations of finite groups."
Amer. J. Math. 93 (1971), 857-866. [MR 316540](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=316540) [DOI: 10.2307/2373739](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2373739).

Comment: What does $x^y$ mean in this context?

Comment: Here $x^y=y^{-1}xy$

Comment: So the last condition is equivalent to $xyx=y$, right?

Comment: the last condition for the generalised quaternion $2$-group, yes

Comment: @RobertChamberlain If you don't mind, is it widely used that $x^y = y^{-1}xy$, or could it also mean $yxy^{-1}$ in other places?

Comment: @Ovi It is certainly the most common use. For $x$ in a set $X$ and $y$ in a group $G$, $x^y$ is natural notation for any right action of $G$ on $X$. When $X=G$ the two most common right actions are conjugation and right multiplication. $xy$ is more natural for multiplication so $x^y$ is generally used for conjugation. It would be unusual to define $x^y=yxy^{-1}$ as this is not generally a right action.

Comment: Ah okay thanks!