# What is the minimal possible order of an $n$-universal group?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-groups, extremal-combinatorics

Suppose $G$ is a finite group. We call $G$ $n$-universal iff any group $H$, such that $|H| \leq n$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $G$. Here are some examples of universal groups:

> $S_n$ is $n$-universal.

Proof of this fact (usually known as Cayley theorem) can be found in any group-theory textbook.

> Suppose $p$ is a prime and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, that satisfies the conditions:
>
> - $p^n+1$ is composite
> - If $p = 2$, then $n \geq 4$
>
> Then $S_{p^n}$ is $p^n + 1$ universal

That follows from Cayley theorem and [the fact that all incompressible groups are $p$-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3250430/407165).

> If $G$ is $n$-universal, then it is $(n-1)$-universal.

Trivially follows from the definition

Let's define $UG(n)$ as the minimal possible order of an $n$-universal group.

> Does there exist some explicit formula (or at least asymptotic) for $UG(n)$?

I only managed to prove the three following facts:

> $UG(n)$ is monotonously non-decreasing

Follows from the third example

> $UG(n) \leq n!$

Follows from Cayley theorem

> $UG(n) \geq e^{\psi(n)}$, where $\psi$ stands for the [Second Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function)

Follows from Lagrange theorem

Comment: Write $u=$"$UG$". Exercise:  $u(p)=pu(p-1)$ for $p$ prime; $u(4)=24$, $u(6)=120=6!/6$. $u(8)$, $u(9)$ and $u(10)$ should be not too hard to determine.

Comment: At least for small cases, this question basically boils down to this question:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121719/richness-of-the-subgroup-structure-of-p-groups

Comment: All the groups of order $8$ embed in a group of order $32$ and no smaller. It easily follows that $u(8)=32*3*5*7$. Also this sequence is not in the OEIS.

Comment: I think it's then not hard to show that $u(9)=u(10)=2^5*3^3*5*7$. Clearly it can be no smaller. To construct an example, start with $C_7\times C_5\times C_9\times C_3$, then make your group of order $32$ act on this, where an index $2$ subgroup centralises everything, and something outside the index $2$ subgroup acts by inversion.

Comment: I didn't actually check carefully, but I wouldn't be surprised if $u(12)=u(11)$. It fact, it seems plausible that $u(n)$ is just the product of $u(p^m)$ where $p$ ranges over the primes less or equal to $n$ and $p^m$ is the largest power of $p$ less or equal to $n$, in which case the question reduces to the prime power case (which seems hard anyway, according to the discussion on MO).

Comment: See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09286) where $UG(n)$ is determined for $1\leq n\leq 15$.  Perhaps of particular interest to @verret is that $u(11)\neq u(12)$.  (It turns out that $u(12) = 2u(11)$ but $u(13)=u(14)=u(15) = 13u(12)$.)

Comment: @James You could probably make that an answer, as I doubt we're going to get much better than that.

Comment: @verret Okay. I've added some summary notes which I hope will improve the quality of the "answer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09286) 2017 paper by Heffernan, MacHale and McCann determines $UG(n)$ for $1\leq n\leq 15$.  Their numeric results appear in their Table 5 at the end of the paper, just before the references.

In addition to those numeric values, they determine the groups of order $UG(n)$ showing that, in particular, the group is not necessarily unique.  For $6\leq n\leq 15$, it is smaller than the symmetric group $S_n$.

Along the same lines that @verret had discussed in the comments, they prove an interesting lower bound.  If $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_m$ are the primes not exceeding $n$ and if, for each $i$, $p_i^{k_i}$ is the largest power of $p_i$ less than or equal to $n$, then a group $G$ that embeds all groups of order at most $n$ is divisible by $p_1^{2k_1 - 1}p_2^{2k_2 - 1}\cdots p_m^{2k_m - 1}$.  (Their Lemma 2.)

Also of interest is their Lemma 6 which asserts that this lower bound is not achieved for $p^k$ with $p$ an odd prime and $k\geq 3$.  (The order of a group must be divisible by at least $p^6$ to embed all groups of order  $p^3$.)

(They also consider the question of the minimal order of a group that embeds all groups of order $n$ (again, for $1\leq n\leq 15$), but not necessarily all groups of order *at most* $n$.)